# How to import an arbitrary GIT branch into a Bazaar repo on Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, git, bazaar

I would like to [import](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Imports) an arbitrary GIT branch (NOT `master`) into a Bazaar repo on Launchpad, but when [requesting a new code import](https://code.launchpad.net/+code-imports/+new) Launchpad by default imports the `HEAD` of the `master` branch. So how can I import, for example, the `2.1.x` branch of the [LyX GIT repository](http://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=summary), if the URL for the repo is `git://git.lyx.org/lyx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import the `2.1.x` branch of the LyX GIT repo, when [requesting a new code import](https://code.launchpad.net/+code-imports/+new) on Launchpad you need to append `,branch=$NAME` to the GIT repo URL. So in this case it would be:

```
git://git.lyx.org/lyx,branch=2.1.x
```

This feature doesn't seem to be documented on Launchpad's [help page for VcsImports](https://help.launchpad.net/VcsImports).